# Почему нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В Интернете нашёл следующее предложение:
 ***Настроенный с самого начала на ничью, молодой шахматист в игре с гроссмейстером не сумел использовать выгодного положения своей ладьи.***
 Почему здесь поставили запятую? Ведь если определяемое слово стоит после причастного оборота, то запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае причастный оборот имеет обстоятельственное значение *причины* (не смог выиграть, поскольку был настроен на ничью), поэтому он обособлен.

Answer (score 2):

Как написал Alex_ander, причастный оборот имеет обстоятельственное значение причины.

Сравните:

Настроенный на ничью, шахматист не сумел победить.
Аккуратно причесанный шахматист не сумел победить.

Первое предложение можно перестроить, не меняя смысла:

Будучи настроенным на ничью, шахматист не сумел победить.

А второе нельзя.